# Is it possible for an expat living in UAE to go to Umrah by road?

Tags: borders, road-trips, uae, saudi-arabia

I am an Indian citizen living in Abu Dhabi, would like to perform Umrah with family. I would like to travel by road in own car. Is it possible to do so with out taking any travel agency package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible:

> The expatriates in UAE can no longer take their private vehicles for Umrah. The rules changed since 1 Jan 2016 and travelling for Umrah is now only possible by Air or through the authorised Umrah Agents' buses.

([Source](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g293991-i4477-k11785076-Umrah_by_private_car_from_UAE-Saudi_Arabia.html))

Another newer source:

> i checked with the travel agent, expat cannot go to saudi for umrah in private vehicle only emarati can go, expats can go by air or via saudi gov bus service or umrah agent bus service but not in private vehicle

([Source](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g293991-i4477-k11785076-o10-Umrah_by_private_car_from_UAE-Saudi_Arabia.html))

Comment: The source you mentioned is one year old. Is there any update in that, or is that relevant?

Comment: @MuhammedShihabudeenLabbaA updated

Comment: This was implemented to limit the number of cars, parking space for thousands of cars is quite difficult due to the nature of Makkah as it's in the middle of mountains.